# Find the standard matrix representation of the linear transformation T in M2,2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

let  $T: M_{2,2} \rightarrow M_{2,2}$ be a linear transformation defined by:

$$T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b\\
        c & d\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}a + b& b + a \\ c - d&d+b\end{bmatrix}
$$

Find the standard matrix for $S$ by using the standard basis of $M_{2,2}$

This is what i've done so far:

$$T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1& 1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix} = x_1
$$

$$T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1& 1 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix} = x_2
$$

$$T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        1 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} = x_3
$$

$$T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}0& 0\\ -1&1\end{bmatrix} = x_4
$$

But I'm not too sure where to go from here. All I know that these need to somehow become part of a larger matrix

Comment: Would you know how to find the matrix representation of a transformation on $\mathbb R^4$? If so, think of the standard basis you've used as an ordered set of four column vectors in $\mathbb R^4$? and do the same thing.

Comment: @Dan so are you suggesting that the standard matrix for the transformation would simply be $[x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4]$?

Comment: That's correct `:)`

Comment: @Dan so would the standard matrix be a 2 x 8 matrix or a 4 x 4 matrix? Still a little confused

Comment: Yes, it would be a $4\times 4$ matrix. I'll provide an answer below if you'd like, but Omnomnomnom explains it correctly below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ denote the standard basis. Note that
$$
T(v_1) = T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1& 1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix} = 
1v_1 + 1v_2 +0v_3 + 0v_4\\
T(v_2) = T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1\\
        0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1& 1 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix} = 
1v_1 + 1v_2 + 0v_3 + 1v_4\\
T(v_3) = T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        1 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} = 
0v_1 + 0v_2 + 1v_3 + 0v_4\\
T(v_4) = T \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}0& 0\\ -1&1\end{bmatrix} = 
0v_1 + 0v_2 + (-1)v_3 + 1v_4
$$
It follows that the matrix of the transformation is given by
$$
S = 
\pmatrix{
1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&1&0&1
}
$$